# Invert a Map object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was wondering, what is the most convenient way to invert keys and values in a Map. Is there any builtin method or should it be done by iterating over keys and values?

```
const map: Map<string, number> = new Map()
```

```
const inverse: Map<number, string>
```

Comment: How do you want duplicates to be handled?

Comment: @NicholasTower An invertible map should be a one - to - one relation without any duplicate in values.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could pass the inverse tuples to the constructor, using `Array.from` and `Array#reverse`:

```
new Map(Array.from(origMap, a => a.reverse()))
```

See it run on an example:

```js
const origMap = new Map([[1, "a"],[2, "b"]]);
console.log(...origMap);

// Reverse:
const inv = new Map(Array.from(origMap, a => a.reverse()));
console.log(...inv);
```

Comment: What a great one liner i like this one the most.

Comment: It could also be `new Map(Array.from(origMap, entry => [entry[1], entry[0]]))`. Unlike with the original solution, TypeScript won't complain about it

Comment: @Max you should submit that as a separate answer.

Comment: I used a map to get the result: `new Map([...map]).map(([k,v]) => [v,k]))`

Comment: @TalesMGodois, if you fix the parentheses, that is what is already presented in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550623/5459839), but it unnecessarily creates an intermediate array.

Comment: @trincot that is the same answer that is true, I was trying to say that the reverse function wasn't necessary. Also just to understand, the extra array that you meant is on the [...map] ou that one generated on the .map function?

Comment: [...map] is the intermediate array that is not created in my answer.

Comment: `No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(iterable?: Iterable<readonly [unknown, unknown]>): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(entries?: readonly (readonly [unknown, unknown])[]): Map<unknown, unknown>', gave the following error.ts(2769)`

Answer (score 6):

Given the assumption that there are no duplicate values, you can do an inverse like this:

```
const map: Map<string, number> = new Map();
map.set('3', 3);
map.set('4', 4);

const inverse: Map<number, string> = new Map();
map.forEach((value, key) => inverse.set(value, key));
```

Comment: `.reduce` would also works and would provide a more functional approach.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Maps don't have a `.reduce` method, so i assume you mean converting it to an array and then doing a reduce.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the spread operator on your original map to obtain key-value array pairs which you can `.map` to swap each pair. Lastly, dump the result into the `Map` constructor for your copy. Any duplicate keys will be lost.

```js
const orig = new Map([["a", 1], ["b", 2]]);
const cpy = new Map([...orig].map(e => e.reverse()));

console.log([...orig]);
console.log([...cpy]);
```

This is terse but does involve an extra array creation as pointed out by the inimitable [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550463/invert-a-map-object/56550623#comment127023517_56550600). That's only an issue if the maps are large.

By the way, if your original values are indeed numbers and aren't sparse, consider using a plain old array for your "flipped" map. This might improve performance and semantics, entirely dependent on your use case.